# Highcharts: Change spline line color according to y value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My yAxis section looks like this:

```
yAxis: {
                    title: {
                      text: 'Height of tide<br>in feet.'
                        },
                        gridLineColor: '#197F07',
                        gridLineWidth: 0,
                        lineWidth:1,
                        plotLines: [{
                            color: '#FF0000',
                            width: 1,
                            value: 0
                    }]
                },
```

How to I change the color of the line (to red) for y = <0?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [negativeColor](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.negativeColor) property to change the colors. 
The color for the parts of the graph or points that are below the threshold. Default threshold is 0.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [-6.4, -5.2, -3.0, 0.2, 2.3, 5.5, 8.4, 8.3, 5.1, 0.9, -1.1, -4.0],
    negativeColor: '#FF0000'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.negativeColor

Comment: Thanks, I had not spotted that in the docs. Where do I place the negativeColor property in that yAxis section I'm using?